# Access to LED downlight drivers

Tags: electrical, lighting

Helping my son build a house and he went with Lithonia WF4 LED lighting (pic attached).   I know all connections need to be "permanently accessible" but mounting these drivers and connection in the joists with only a 4" opening for the removable downlight as "access" doesn't seem reasonable access. Is there a better approach?

[image: Full picture of driver and fixture]
[image: Driver for LED recessed lighting]

Comment: How to video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MgmSukybivo

Comment: Place the driver at a more accesible place and use an extention cord between the fixture and the driver. The extention cords are supplier available

Comment: the driver is smaller than the opening, so access is, after pulling the downlight, bringing the driver into the room. if the room is is too small you have a problem.

Comment: I spoke to the inspector today and asked about this issue.  He said as long as you  can reach the driver with one hand, it's "accessible".  I'm not very cool with that and believe we should re-wire the existing 1st floor lamps so that the driver could be pulled out thru the hole for the fixture.   Thanks to Steve for the video link.  While I now believe it will pass code, I'm still not happy with it .

Answer (score 1):

Access to the wiring connections of any can light is based on pulling the light out of the hole, then accessing the connections though that hole.  In this case, the wiring box can be pulled all the way out of the hole so you're in better shape than some situations.

With a good brand name like Lithonia, this are sure to be UL listed which means they should conform to common building codes and have been tested for safety.